Problem with Intel wifi AX210
I have some problems with my new wifi card intel AX210
I am on Ubuntu 24.10
When i boot, no wifi, the airplane mode is on
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    3.541635] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x400410, cnv-id 0x400410 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    3.541652] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: PCI dev 2725/0024, rev=0x420, rfid=0x10d000
[    3.541656] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz
[    3.560776] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.42
[    3.563571] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: loaded firmware version 89.202a2f7b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.128371] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x3f
[    6.128389] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    6.128402] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[    6.128415] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[    6.128438] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0xf0a30903
[    6.128453] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    6.128466] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[    6.128479] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[    6.128491] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x0
[    6.128493] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0xd05c18
[    6.128496] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd05c1c
[    6.128499] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    6.128613] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.128615] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: -1476098256
[    6.128618] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 89.202a2f7b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode
[    6.128620] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x8024290D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    6.128623] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x8317B6A2 | trm_hw_status0
[    6.128625] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x79A0445D | trm_hw_status1
[    6.128627] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x61550723 | branchlink2
[    6.128629] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x5234B4E5 | interruptlink1
[    6.128630] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xD914D563 | interruptlink2
[    6.128632] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x3E99D258 | data1
[    6.128634] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xFA6D1089 | data2
[    6.128636] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xFCDDD120 | data3
[    6.128637] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xA8F0F229 | beacon time
[    6.128639] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x7D8047A3 | tsf low
[    6.128641] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x028ED205 | tsf hi
[    6.128643] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20567CA6 | time gp1
[    6.128645] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x1827CC39 | time gp2
[    6.128646] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x1F30007F | uCode revision type
[    6.128648] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x90D1020C | uCode version major
[    6.128650] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x1A913350 | uCode version minor
[    6.128652] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x08264F23 | hw version
[    6.128654] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xBD045C66 | board version
[    6.128655] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xC93743AD | hcmd
[    6.128657] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x3318A938 | isr0
[    6.128659] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x80562FFC | isr1
[    6.128661] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x8D496320 | isr2
[    6.128662] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x1C627E44 | isr3
[    6.128664] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x51896A5F | isr4
[    6.128666] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xF2834F20 | last cmd Id
[    6.128667] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xFD8D3411 | wait_event
[    6.128669] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xC1D37610 | l2p_control
[    6.128671] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x10E6D835 | l2p_duration
[    6.128673] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xCE5E5CDD | l2p_mhvalid
[    6.128675] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDF7A1248 | l2p_addr_match
[    6.128677] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xA1FB8F59 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    6.128678] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x836444AB | timestamp
[    6.128680] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x7EA1F2BF | flow_handler
[    6.128722] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.128724] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 697380451
[    6.128727] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xEF0EBFBC | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    6.128729] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x2D4ECB0A | umac branchlink1
[    6.128731] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x11924DC6 | umac branchlink2
[    6.128732] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x53C0A5D9 | umac interruptlink1
[    6.128734] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0B0CCF23 | umac interruptlink2
[    6.128736] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x69BDC3C8 | umac data1
[    6.128738] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xF5171505 | umac data2
[    6.128739] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x11205AAD | umac data3
[    6.128741] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xFBB07EB8 | umac major
[    6.128743] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xB4031C15 | umac minor
[    6.128744] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x790085D8 | frame pointer
[    6.128746] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xB748F921 | stack pointer
[    6.128748] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x1B026C19 | last host cmd
[    6.128749] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xCF03ADDF | isr status reg
[    6.128762] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[    6.128764] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xF0A3 | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[    6.128766] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xF0A30903 | IML/ROM error/state
[    6.128778] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[    6.128791] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    6.128799] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    6.128804] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.128809] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.128814] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.128819] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.128825] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.128830] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.128835] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.128840] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.128845] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.128852] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.128859] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.128867] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.128872] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.128877] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[    6.128882] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[    6.128887] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000000F0 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[    6.128900] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x80444556
[    6.128905] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0x0
[    6.128909] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    6.128911] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    7.769094] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[    7.781340] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

I tried all the solutions proposed like rm /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.
But they doesn't work
When i restart the wifi it works :
#!/bin/bash

# Remove the wireless adapter
echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:3b:00.0/remove

sleep 5

# Rescan PCI bus
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan

# Restart networking services
systemctl restart '*etwork*.service'

Dmesg after restarting wifi :
[   83.023989] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x400410, cnv-id 0x400410 wfpm id 0x80000000
[   83.023997] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: PCI dev 2725/0024, rev=0x420, rfid=0x10d000
[   83.024000] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz
[   83.033838] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.42
[   83.034278] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: loaded firmware version 89.202a2f7b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   83.199059] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   83.199076] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   83.199090] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   83.199103] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[   83.202756] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: loaded PNVM version 35148b80
[   83.218124] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[   83.287215] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: base HW address: 10:91:d1:d3:a6:49
[   83.351527] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0
[   84.226001] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   84.226019] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   84.226032] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   84.226045] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[   84.316249] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

Can you help me to have a working wifi at startup please ?
Thanks,
Thomas

i am in the same situation as explained here, maybe it is usefull : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1962550
